# Array: Ascending and Multiplication Table

Tags: python

How to arrange 5 integers using array in ascending order, no use of sort()
then 5x5 multiplication table using array too, like using list, array append.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at what I believe you're asking, mostly because I hope it's educational. You're lucky I'm procrastinating studying at the moment.

**Sorting, because who likes entropy anyway?**
*Bubbles!*
Your first task is to look at the [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), a sorting algorithm that's as simple to code as it is to understand. (It performs poorly with large arrays due to its *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* performance but is probably among the first sorts a lot of people encounter.) I *highly, highly* suggest you understand the algorithm before even thinking about looking at code.

*How does it work?*
Start at the beginning! Look at the first pair of numbers. If they're in the wrong order, swap them. Increment your starting position by 1 and repeat until the end of the array.

*What would this look like in Python?*
I'm glad you asked. You need to loop through the whole array and swap whenever appropriate. Thankfully Python makes swapping very easy, allowing you to pull tricks like `a, b = b, a`. We can (hopefully quickly) write down some code to do what we want:

```
def bubble_sort(array):
    for i in xrange(len(array)):
        for j in xrange(len(array) - i - 1):
            if array[j] > array[j + 1]:
                array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]
    return array
```

This should be straightforward and follows the sorting procedure directly. Pass in an array (or list of numbers) and it will return an array sorted in ascending order.

**Multiplication Table**
I'm assuming you mean something like [this table](https://swansmath3-4.wikispaces.com/file/view/multiplication_table_complete.jpg/56588252/800x600/multiplication_table_complete.jpg) that you learn in first grade. The requirement I'm imposing on your vague wording is that we want to return a 2D array where the first row is multiples of 0, the second is multiples of 1, etc. This goes for the columns as well, since multiplication tables are symmetric between rows and columns. There are a number of possible approaches, but I'm only going to consider the one I personally find the most elegant and Pythonic. Python comes packed with great list comprehension, so why not make use of it? Try this:

```
table = [[x*y for x in xrange(6)] for y in xrange(6)]
```

This creates a 6x6 matrix, i.e. the multiplication table from 0–5. Take some time to really understand this code. I think that list comprehension is absolutely fundamental to Python and is something that sets it apart. If you look at the `(i, j)`th element of the array, you'll see that it equals `ij`. For example, `table[3][2] == 6` is true.

I desperately hope you learned something useful from this. Next time you post a question, hopefully you'll give us more to work on.